# Div which appears moves me to the top of page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I use jQuery to show new div. This is a semi-transparent div which appears after a click with function fadeIn, when I scroll down, and click on the element under the page, then this div appears (after click event) but it moves to the top of a page, it doesn't appear there where I clicked. Everythings works good, but the div goes up to the top of page, so when I close this div, I have to scroll down again... How can I fix this?

Comment: While it sounds like you did a good job of describing how your problem appears, you will need to provide a JSFiddle or at least some code if you'd like to get some constructive feedback.

Comment: Put some code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that would be better to find the problem